# Select2 - Search within the whole content not just start with

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I'm using select2 and I want to allow the user to search the entire word not just the beginning.

For example let's say I have the following list:

first place moto
secondo place moto
third place moto

If I type: "first place" I get one element but if I type "first moto" I don't have any result.

Is there a way to configure select2 to implement such a solution? Passing for example a custom matcher etc..

Comment: Hope its help https://select2.github.io/examples.html#matcher

Comment: You are right the question is duplicated